# WebView/AlertView

Tags: ios

I am using the following code:

```
- (IBAction)callZH:(id)sender {


UIWebView *callWebview = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
NSURL *telURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:mynumberhere"];
[callWebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:telURL]];

[self.view addSubview:callWebview];
}
```

The above code works great. However, When user taps button that the above IBAction is connected to, an alert view will automatically pop up showing the Tel# with 2 buttons bellow Tel# cancel or call. How can I set the title above the Tel# in the alert view?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, when I want to call, I don't use a webview, but rather I use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@", phoneNumber]]];
```

An alert is good practice, so create whatever sort of alert you want with whatever title you want, and if the user chooses to proceed, you can invoke the above code to make the call without any further user-interface interruption.